# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't seem to figure out why I am getting this error I've seen solutions for the error but none of those were using AJAX to get the data if anyone could help that would be great here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function updatetabel() {
        console.log("update");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/main",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "",
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                console.log("succes!");
                console.log()
                $(".table-hover-cells").remove();
                $.each(result, function(index, value) {
                    console.log("update_tabel");
                    var content = "<table class=\"table-hover-cells" +
                        this[0] + "\" id=\"hover-table\">" + "<thead>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" +
                        this.Name + "</td>" + "<td>" +
                        this.Description + "</td>" + "<td>" +
                        this.Status + "</td>" + "<td>" +
                        this.Date + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "</thead>" + "</table>"

                    $("inv").append(content);
                })
                console.log("tabel_update");
            },
            error: function(result, thrownError) {
                console.log("Failure!")
                console.log(result)
            }
        });

    }

    updatetabel();
    setInterval(function() {
        updatetabel()
    }, 100000);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tbody tr td').on('hover', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('bg');
    });
});
```

Comment: Which line in your code is throwing that error?

Comment: Any reason your leaving the dataType blank, and not putting 'json'?

Comment: where are using using `.length` ?

Comment: thnx for your help it helped me  finding the error =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line in your success callback throws the error:

```
$.each(result, function(index, value) {
    ...
}
```

Most likely, your 'result' is not a valid response to your request, and $.each requires a valid array to iterate through. Check the XHR response of your ajax call first to see if an array is returned. It's also better to define your dataType too.